# Is my router robbing my broadband by lowering connection speed?

Tags: networking

I have 800 mbps  cable internet service from Xfinity and my own MB8600 Motorola modem connected to a ASUS RT-AX1800S Router. When i connect my computer directly to modem I get download speed of 950 mbps down and 24 mbps up. When connecting the modem to the router, my speed drops to 176 to 300 mbps. no matter what I do, i can't increase the speed for the three destops I have connected by ethernet cat6 cables.
Iv'e tried different modems and router, tested all cables including coax line and connectors and all check out I have connected networks in the past with no problems and 300 mbps is not bad speed, but I'm paying for 800 and if I am not getting it then I can lower my tier to reflect the correct pricing. Any Ideas what could be slowing the broadband between the modem and router? All is LAN connections wifi works good but slower than ethernet connections I need for hard wired computers and tv's.
Any advice would be helpful

Comment: A router will have an internal processing speed, this is not the speed of the connector, but the speed of the processor capable of handling this much traffic. It is very possible the processor of the router simply can't keep up. This can be easily tested by doing a speedtest on one computer with no traffic, then doing a speedtest on all 3 computers at the same time. If you see a clear limit that is always the same, then the router is not fast enough. Consumer graded routers often are not fast enough for high speeds.

Comment: Mmmh... That Asus router should be able to handle the load. Makes me wonder if the connection between modem and router is actually established as a full-duplex gigabit connection. From past experience I know that some modems don't always handle auto-negotiate well. Try changing the UTP cable between modem and router. Try a Cat5E cable instead of a CAT6. A much longer (or shorter) cable may also help (changes timing slightly which can help). And use a regular patch cable and not a cross-cable. Shouldn't make a difference for Gigabit auto-negotiate but some devices just don't like it.

Comment: @LPChip The router is not the bottleneck All Asus RT-AX models can handle full gigabit on the wired connections, including WAN and have enough CPU power to handle the NAT at a fully saturated WAN load.

Comment: @tonny Your comments about downgrading to cat5e and changing to a longer cable robbed your previous comment of credibity.

Comment: This modem has four LAN ports under a plate on the rear. I know these are for port bonding channels which I do not want to use, but is it worth a try to use one of the other ports in case port #1 is not working to standards?  Motorola says this is a bridging modem and only should use ports 1 or 2. Maybe over did it on modem purchase for what I need.